# how long does the root system on Malabar Spinach need to grow before it will show any growth?

Tags: growth, roots, spinach

I have a red and a green Malabar spinach, and it seems to be waiting to grow, how long will it likely be before i see any real results?

Comment: it grew about 1 foot last night (3 inches of rain), so this is just a curiosity question now, not a why doesn't it seem to be growing question now.